# SLF4J binding when adding an external jar file to my maven project

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-spark, logging, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am quite new to Spring boot. I use intellij ide. I am trying to run a class found in an external jar file. This jar file contains a SPARK application written in scala. So, I have added the jar file to the dependencies. When I tested it in a separate class it worked fine. However, when I tried to run it in my spring boot mvc project, I encountered that SLF4Js were binding hindering my app to start.

I have tried to exclude log4j from my dependencies (see the code below), following some stackoverflow posts. However, it did not work out.

ps. I have also added spark.assembly jar file.

How can I solve this issue?

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>softuni</groupId>
    <artifactId>mvc-blog</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cosine-lsh</groupId>
            <artifactId>cosine-lsh</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spark.version>1.4.1</spark.version>
    </properties>


</project>
```

And the error I get:

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:.../BLOG/cosine-lsh.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:.../BLOG/spark-1.4.1/lib/spark-assembly-1.4.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/n12017/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "restartedMain" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: LoggerFactory is not a Logback LoggerContext but Logback is on the classpath. Either remove Logback or the competing implementation (class org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory loaded from file:/S:/Staff_files/Mehmet/Projects/JAVA_SPRING_PROJECTS/BLOG/cosine-lsh.jar). If you are using WebLogic you will need to add 'org.slf4j' to prefer-application-packages in WEB-INF/weblogic.xml Object of class [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory] must be an instance of class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Here is what I experienced and solved the issue. this might be beneficial for those beginners like me.

What I first did before was adding the jar file manually to the dependencies under project structure -> modules -> dependencies. And then I changed my pom.xml by adding

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>cosine-lsh</groupId>
            <artifactId>cosine-lsh</artifactId>           
</dependency>
```

However, this was not a correct or safe way to add an external jar file to a mvn project as I understood. Anyway, by applying the procedure below my issue was solved.

First I changed my directory to the one having my related pom.xml file.
Then, I applied the script below. Note that I am explicitely telling the mvn the 
name of the groupid, artifact id and version.

```
mvn install:install-file -
Dfile=...\...\cosine-lsh.jar \ -DgroupId=cosine-lsh -DartifactId=cosinelsh \ -Dversion=1.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

As a last step I added the dependency to my pom.xml file as below:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>cosine-lsh</groupId>
            <artifactId>cosinelsh</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

As for my SPARK configuration:

The changes above enabled the spring code to run without complaining from binding although it kept throwing warnings as below:

```
    SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/n12017/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/n12017/.m2/repository/cosine-lsh/cosinelsh/1.0/cosinelsh-1.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
    SLF4J: Actual binding is of type 
[ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
```

Last but not the least, there appeared another binding issue when using SPARK which was jackson object. I got rid of this issue by adding a exclusion as shown below:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think your cosine-lsh.jar alos contains slf4j classes especially Log4jLoggerFactory. Is it possible to remove them from jar?

Comment: Yes @javasenior exactly.But I am trying to find a way to do it.

Comment: Try to exclude classes from jar. Try it with the apache shade plugin. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html may help you.

Comment: In Intellij Idea on the Maven Projects perspective you can see all the dependency tree. Search there for slf4j artifact and see where does it came from. Cause I suppose you have more slf4j jars in the classpath. Then in the pom.xml declare it as an excluded one.